# Split a text file based on title

Tags: java, text

I've got a text file which I need to read only the numerical digits, and then populate an array with these.

```
LOCATION
6     7
POINT
8     9
JOBS
1     4
4     9
11    8
9     6
5     2
```

I know how to read from a file, below is my code, but I just do not know how to read ONLY these numbers. I'm not sure how to use the split method properly.

```
BufferedReader objReader = null;
   try {
      String strCurrentLine;

      objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Jobs.txt"));

   while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(strCurrentLine); //test
   }

  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would have to split, then test if is an Integer

```
while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String words [] = strCurrentLine.split ("\\s+");
    for (String word : words) {
        try {
            Integer.valueOf (word);
            System.out.println(word); 
        } catch NumberFormatException e { // do nothing}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to anything that involves interpreting formatted data, I always like to use regex:

```
String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append("\n" + line);
}

objReader.close();

List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(builder.toString());
while (m.find()) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}

numbers.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want the numbers to be grouped by line, try this:

```
String line;
List<List<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
while ((line = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (m.find()) {
        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }

    numbers.add(nums);
}

objReader.close();

numbers.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
6
7
8
9
1
4
4
9
11
8
9
6
5
2
```

Although I have to admit, Scary Wombat's solution is much shorter and cleaner.

Comment: *Scary Wombat's solution is much shorter and cleaner* - thanks, but I also don't like to catch exceptions to control business logic.